# Не получается обработать(или отправить) пост запрос в опенкарт

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, opencart

В админке в редактировании продукта я создал кнопку. При нажатии на неё должен быть отправлен запрос к контроллеру product и вызвать мой метод. Я через ajax отправляю пост запрос и в нём передаю тестовый параметр. Но в методе контроллера при проверке его нет в массиве пост запроса.

Вот код в View продукта (JavaScript):

```js
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/generateInstances&user_token={{ user_token }}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "mypost" : 'mytest'
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data instanceof Object) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            }
        });
```

А вот тот метод, который вызывается в контроллере Product (PHP):

```php
        $json = array();
        $json['test'] = 'test';

        if (isset($this->request->post['mypost'])) {
            $json['has'] = 'value';
        } else {
            $json['no'] = 'value';
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

И в таком случае показывает что нет такого ключа. Но если же я дописываю ключи к url (т.е. как в гет запросе), то через $this->request->get мне показывает что этот ключ есть.

Что я делаю неправильно? Я понимаю что я либо отправляю неправильно, либо неправильно принимаю запрос.

версия Opencart3

Comment: попробуйте отправить запрос `$.ajax` без сериализации данных, а именно, уберите `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/generateInstances&user_token={{ user_token }}',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: 'mypost=mytest',
        success: function (data) {
            // ... ...
```